# Chained string substitions in gmake

Tags: gnu-make

In GNU make, I'd like to perform multiple string substitutions on a blob of text containing several "placeholders", e.g.:

```
MYTEXT:= blabla _FIRST_PLACEHOLDER_ blabla _SECOND_PLACEHOLDER_whateverblabla_THIRD_PLACEHOLDER_blablabla
```

So I'd like to replace the "placeholders" with values as follows:

```
_FIRST_PLACEHOLDER_ => FIRST_VAL
_SECOND_PLACEHOLDER_ => SECOND_VAL
_THIRD_PLACEHOLDER_ => THIRD_VAL
...
```

The following shows a hideous way of obtaining the result I'd like:

```
$(subst _FIRST_PLACEHOLDER_,FIRST_VAL, $(subst _SECOND_PLACEHOLDER_,SECOND_VAL, $(subst _THIRD_PLACEHOLDER_,THIRD_VAL, $(MYTEXT))))
```

A solution would be straightforward to find outside the make world, but is there a better way than the above to perform such a recursive substitution while remaining within the confines of make? I tried using $(foreach), but this simply concatenates the result of each substitution applied once to the initial `$(MYTEXT)`.

Comment: How many placeholders do you have?  A recursive function could be created to do it with `$(call ...)` but the implementation would be complex enough that it's not worth it unless you have a lot of these and do it often.

Comment: About 9 of them.

Comment: The examples that you are showing are very different from the description you are giving. If you just want to achieve a substitution like the `MYTEXT :=` snippet, it is utterly sufficient to just write `MYTEXT := blabla$(FIRST_PLACEHOLDER) blabla $(SECOND_PLACEHOLDER) etc.` with those variables properly set before. If however you want to replace patterns which are created by a substitution (this is what I understand as "recursive") themselves, you have to use a function and be prepared for a stack overflow as the substitution can in principle go on forever.

Answer (score 1):

### Iterative solution

This solution requires overwriting of the variables `_p` and `_x`.

```make
# -*- gnu-make -*-
ORIGINAL         := 123__PLACE_HOLDER__1567__PLACE_HOLDER__2890
REPLACEMENT_LIST :=       \
    __PLACE_HOLDER__1=ABC \
    __PLACE_HOLDER__2=DEF \

_replace1 = $(eval _x := $(subst $(word 1,$(1)),$(word 2,$(1)),$(_x)))
replace   = $(strip \
    $(eval _x := $(strip $(2))) \
    $(foreach _p,$(strip $(1)),$(call _replace1,$(subst =, ,$(_p)))) \
    $(_x) \
    $(eval _x :=) \
)

$(info ORIGINAL:    '$(ORIGINAL)')
$(info REPLACEMENT: '$(call replace,$(REPLACEMENT_LIST),$(ORIGINAL))')

.PHONY: all
all:
```

Example run:

```
$ make 
ORIGINAL:    '123__PLACE_HOLDER__1567__PLACE_HOLDER__2890'
REPLACEMENT: '123ABC567DEF890'
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

### Recursive solution

This solution has the advantage of not modifying any variable.

```make
_replace2 = $(subst $(word 1,$(1)),$(word 2,$(1)),$(2))
_replace1 = $(call replace,$(2),$(call _replace2,$(subst =, ,$(1)),$(3)))
replace   = $(if $(1),$(call _replace1,$(firstword $(1)),$(wordlist 2,1000000,$(1)),$(2)),$(2))
```

or

```make
_replace1 = $(subst $(word 1,$(1)),$(word 2,$(1)),$(2))
replace   = $(if $(1),$(call replace,$(wordlist 2,1000000,$(1)),$(call _replace1,$(subst =, ,$(firstword $(1))),$(2))),$(2))
```

Comment: Phew!! As @MadScientist commented, this is sufficiently complex so as to only be used if unavoidable. Thanks!

Comment: That's why you write such macros only once and put them in a library that your build system templates can use.

Comment: ... and why [such a library](https://gmsl.sourceforge.io) already exists for certain operations ;)